# Key Value Database For Windows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, memcached, key-value

Other than MongoDB and Memcached, what key-value stores run on Windows? Most of the ones I've seen seem to only run on Linux (Hypertable, Redis, Lightcloud).

Related links:
[Is there a business proven cloud store / Key=>Value Database? (Open Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639545/is-there-a-business-proven-cloud-store-keyvalue-database-open-source)
http://www.metabrew.com/article/anti-rdbms-a-list-of-distributed-key-value-stores/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would take a look at this article from [highscalability.com](http://highscalability.com/drop-acid-and-think-about-data).  It describes a few options that you may want to consider, including [Tokyo Cabinet/Tyrant](http://tokyocabinet.sourceforge.net/), [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home).

Comment: Couch an Mongo aren't really key-value though.

Answer (score 6):

[Berkeley DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) is [available](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html). I'm surprised no-one has mentioned it yet.

You can build it on Windows either with a native or Cygwin toolchain, but it's probably best with MSVC if you're going to be linking it with `C#`.

Comment: It's pricing for commercial use is above the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Redis is C99 (Posix).  It should be trivial to build and run it on cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the CouchDb installer for Windows

http://people.apache.org/~mhammond/dist/0.11.0/

Comment: CouchDb is great fun, I'm getting a lot of mileage out of it at the moment, with the fact that you can use Ubuntu One to synchronize. Well you can on Linux. But I don't think it would be too hard to implement on Windows, as long as the ubuntu guys have let the REST protocol free and easy with some Authorization.